# stack barcharts in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

is there a comforable way to combine different `lattice` `barchart` plots to get a stacked `barchart`? (I can use `as.layer`, but then the two plots are behind each other and not stacked). Example:

```
library(lattice); library(dplyr); library(latticeExtra)

# sample data
barley %>% filter(variety %in% c("Trebi","Velvet","Peatland"))

b1   <- barley %>% filter(site == "Morris")
b2   <- barley %>% filter(site == "Duluth")
b1a2 <- barley %>% filter(site %in% c("Morris","Duluth"))

# stacked plot
plotorg <- barchart(yield ~ variety | year, data = b1a2,
                    groups = site, stack = TRUE)

# two barcharts that I want stack together
plot1   <- barchart(yield ~ variety | year, data = b1,
                    groups = site, stack = TRUE)

plot2   <- barchart(yield ~ variety | year, data = b2,
                    groups = site, stack = TRUE)

plot1 + plot2 # bars are behind each other and not stacked
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot combine lattice plots to create a stacked plot. When use use layers, each layer does not know how the data in other layers is rendered so the bars cannot appear at the end of other bars. If you want to stack you'll need to plot them together as you've done in the first plot.

Comment: @MrFlick but the informations are in the plots, so I see no reason why it should not be possible. If I have normal grouping and additional grouping for stacking it will be a problem too. (there is only one group parameter if I understand it correct

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible, I'm saying that's something lattice doesn't have any support for. That `+` operation doesn't check that both plots are using the exact same panel function or attempt to manipulate the rendered data in any way. It simply plots layers on top of each other. If that's something you want to implement, you will have to do all the offset calculations yourself.

Comment: @MrFlick yes, thanks. I think `+` ist also not `lattice` but `latticeExtra`. But there might be someone how has implementet this before (or a package)

Comment: Well, asking for package recommendations is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. (I consider latticeExtra part of lattice because it's made by the same guy).

Comment: @MrFlick why sould a package recommendation or function recommendation be offtopic... it is no question to "what is the best package" it is a "is there a package that make my day"  question... I do not see the problem